# Which design pattern for ordering and filtering data?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I need to filter and order data entries after criteria that a user selects through a dropdown. Selectable will be things like "newest entries first", "oldest entries first", "lowest price first" etc.

I could just create an enum for the options and switch/case where I retrieve the data, but I'd rather do this in an easily extendable way.

What design pattern would fit the situation best?

Comment: winforms, wpf, silverlight, webforms or mvc?

Comment: I suppose the STRATEGY pattern would do..

Comment: WebForms, but isnt that a generic problem?

Comment: Yes it's a generic problem doesn't matter about the UI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everyone has mentioned the strategy pattern. Just thought I'd post my simple implementation. No need to make it more complicated than necessary.

```
public enum SortMethod
{
    Newest,
    Oldest,
    LowestPrice,
}

public class Foo
{
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}
    public decimal Price {get;set;}
}


...
var strategyMap = new Dictionary<SortMethod, Func<IEnumerable<Foo>, IEnumerable<Foo>>>
                  {
                      { SortMethod.Newest, x => x.OrderBy(y => y.Date) },
                      { SortMethod.Oldest, x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Date) },
                      { SortMethod.LowestPrice, x => x.OrderBy(y => y.Price) }
                  };

...
var unsorted = new List<Foo>
               {
                   new Foo { Date = new DateTime(2012, 1, 3), Price = 10m },
                   new Foo { Date = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1), Price = 30m },
                   new Foo { Date = new DateTime(2012, 1, 2), Price = 20m }
               };

var sorted = strategyMap[SortMethod.LowestPrice](unsorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not always good at naming the right pattern to fit my thought, but my initial thought is why not make a simple class for each option and implement IComparer(T) and then load those items as your dropdown options.  You would likely only need a name property in addition to the interface method.

```
public class NameSorter: IComparer<WhateverObj>
{
public String DisplayName;    

public int Compare(WhateverObj x, WhateverObj y)
{

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this sounds like a job for the [Strategy pattern](http://www.yetanotherchris.me/home/2009/1/28/c-design-patterns-the-strategy-pattern.html). You'll recognise it as this already features heavily in the .NET framework.

Here's an example using IComparer, or using the LINQ extension methods in 3.5 which I prefer. You'll still need to add a factory-style method to the base class that works out which comparer it should use, or you could store this as part of the data in the drop down list.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    List<User> users = new List<User>();
    users.Add(new User() { Name = "Larry", Age = 35 });
    users.Add(new User() { Name = "Bob", Age = 25 });
    users.Add(new User() { Name = "Brian", Age = 30 });

    NameComparer sorter = new NameComparer();
    IEnumerable<User> sortedUsers = sorter.Sort(users);

    NameComparer35 sorter35 = new NameComparer35();
    IEnumerable<User> sortedUsers35 = sorter35.Sort(users);
}

public abstract class MyComparer<T> : IComparer<T> where T: User
{
    public abstract int Compare(T x, T y);

    public IEnumerable<T> Sort(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        items.ToList().Sort(this);
        return items;
    }
}

public abstract class MyComparer35<T> where T : User
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<T> Sort(IEnumerable<T> items);
}

public class NameComparer35 : MyComparer35<User>
{
    public override IEnumerable<User> Sort(IEnumerable<User> items)
    {
        return items.OrderBy(u => u.Name);
    }
}

public class NameComparer : MyComparer<User>
{
    public override int Compare(User x, User y)
    {
        return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);
    }
}

public class AgeComparer : MyComparer<User>
{
    public override int Compare(User x, User y)
    {
        return x.Age.CompareTo(y.Age);
    }
}

public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", Name, Age);
    }
}
```